# Why disabling dates in IE8 not working properly with Jquery date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I currently have a datepicker from jquery where i am disabling  national holidays. It works fine in FF not not in IE 8. In IE i get  the following error message:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'call' of undefined or null reference 
mainsearch_functions.js, line 230 character 7.

the code i am using to block  the holidays is below. Can someone tell me why this does not work on IE 8

```
function nationalDays(date) {

// federal holidays
natDays = [
           [1, 1, 'new years'], 
           [1, 21, 'Birthday of Martin Luther King, Jr.'], 
           [2, 18, 'Washington\'s Birthday'],
           [4, 27, 'Memorial Day'], 
           [7, 4, 'Independence Day'], 
           [9, 2, 'Labor Day'],
           [10, 14, 'Columbus Day'], 
           [11, 11, 'Veterans Day'], 
           [11, 28, 'Thanksgiving Day'],
           [12, 25, 'Christmas Day'], 

         ];
for (var i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
  if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 // ERROR HAPPENS HERE
      && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {

    return [false, natDays[i][2],natDays[i][2]];
  }

}
return [true, '','Must be 5 business days out.'];
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: You say you're getting an error in jquery-validate.js on line 50, but for some reason you think it's coming from the above function ?

Comment: why are you pasing in argument `date` but then immediately creating `var date` ?

Comment: suggest you create a demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: BTW...why is question subject about datepicker, but code is validation plugin code? can disable dates in datepicker if needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing comma in the `natDays` array

```
[12, 25, 'Christmas Day'],
```

I think IE8 inserts a NULL into the array because of this.